# Will the TP Link WDS-3600 work with a 9V 0.6A AC adapter?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, ac-adapter

I just bought this router and on the back it says it consumes 12V 1.5A current and in the package I got 9V 0.6A adapter. Is it good for it and will it work on this power adapter?

I bought the router used on eBay.

Comment: Hi djoleasterix, and welcome. We generally dislike questions that cannot be answered objectively, so I removed the part asking what people think about the hardware.

Comment: Did you buy it in a sealed, retail package? Then it's probably fine, if not, whoever you bought the device from probably bundled it with the wrong adapter.

Comment: No, i bought it used on ebay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that it is **highly unlikely** that, for a device drawing up to 1.5A at 12V, an AC adapter capable of delivering only 0.6A at 9V would be sufficient.

Based on the numbers you gave, the WDS-3600 needs up to 1.5A × 12V = 18W of power.

The AC adapter you got with it can deliver a maximum of 0.6A × 9V = 5.4W, or about one third of what the router is stated as requiring at most.

What's more, the adapter is underrated on both current *and* voltage.

The undervoltage *might possibly* be acceptable, but such a large difference (25% lower than rated) is fairly likely to lead to unpredictable behavior and erratic errors. To ensure proper operation, the voltage must match; a small error can be tolerable, but 25% is not a small error.

The undercurrent is *highly likely to not* be acceptable. From 0.6A to 1.5A is quite a major difference. Larger current rating than needed is acceptable (though, from an efficiency standpoint, not necessarily ideal) but less than needed will at best work, but not reliably. At worst, by using an underrated AC adapter, you can burn out the AC adapter, breaking it and (depending on its internal construction) possibly even causing a fire hazard.

**I would return the router to the place of purchase, explain what happened and tell them that you want one with the correct AC adapter.** My guess is that this is a packaging mistake somewhere along the delivery line.

Comment: Yet, the router is working fine, a was able to turn it on, configure it and connect to it. You think it's dangerous for me and equipment to use it this way?

Comment: @djoleasterix If it didn't need that extra power, why would the manufacturer specify that it does? It is of course possible that it doesn't need it in regular operation, rather only in some specific situation. Maybe it needs that extra power during (for example) a firmware update? I don't know. Which is why I would prefer to play it safe.

Comment: @djoleasterix Glad I could help.